# Mimic spinning wheel in code?

Tags: java, function, logic

I've been searching a lot but I just can see to find any examples of what I'm looking for.

Basically what I want to do is mimic the functionality of spinning a wheel like on wheel of fortune but with no graphics, just code. So what would happen is I'd start the function and then it'd output 1 number per second, then after a certain amount of time it'll start spitting out 1 number every 3 seconds, then every 5 seconds, etc.. until it finally stops and picks 1 number. Kind of like how when you spin a bottle it gradually comes to a stop.

At first I thought I could achieve this using ScheduledExecutors but its really tricky seeing as I have to calculated when to stop the previous task before I start the next one.

Does anyone have a more simple solution?

Comment: You could use [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) every time it prints a number, and increase the sleep time every iteration however you want (linear, quadratic, exponential, etc.) with some randomness added in if necessary.

Comment: But doesn't that pause the whole program? :o

Comment: It pauses the current thread, so if the program is only using one thread, then yes. Is there something you need the program to do *while* it's spitting out numbers? If not, there's no problem with just pausing and resuming.

Comment: So, if I had Thread.sleep in my main() function and I also had a function that ran a runnable say.. it printed out "hello" every 3 seconds, the thread.sleep wouldn't interrupt that runnable? I'm a pretty new to threads so I guess I'm confused as to which thread that thread.sleep would pause if there are multiple functions within the main().

Comment: That's correct, as far as I understand your question. But it doesn't sound like the program you're attempting to write needs to execute multiple different sections of code asynchronously, right?

Comment: Well I'm planning on putting this spinner in a function and that function will be part of a bigger project. Currently it's a game that other people can connect to, so while other people are playing this function might be initiated by a player in game while other things are happening. So I'm worried that having a thread sleep will affect the other stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to do, in that case. You'll need to edit your question with more detail so we can help.